# How to design the layout of react native screen?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to make the layout of my app very similar to Instagram when it comes to the user profile. here is an example of the layout I am trying to replicate:

[image]

Here is what I have:

[image]

How can I replicate the design? Everything you see on my implementation is its own functional component (that is, the profile pic, the profile stats [posts, followers, following], the bio, and the settings button). This is how I am doing the layout:

```
 <View style={styles.container}>

            
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'left', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                <Text style = {styles.subheader}> {this.state.user.username}'s profile  </Text>

                <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={this.goToSettings}>
                    <Ionicons name="ios-settings" size={24} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>

            <View style = {styles.lineStyle} />
            
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'left', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                 <ProfilePic/>

                 <ProfileStats/>
                 
            </View>

            <ProfileBio />
            
            
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add some more View

this code will help you

```
return (
    <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <text> Chloewest28</text>
        <Icon> Chloewest28</Icon>
      </View>

      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <Image>{/* Profile picture */}</Image>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "column" }}>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Text>1042</Text>
            <Text>1214</Text>
            <Text>1696</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Text>Posts</Text>
            <Text>Followers</Text>
            <Text>Following</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Only think I would add is that the alignment (center) is helpful with this solution.